# hidden area - scroll not displaying

Tags: html, css

Hey Guys I have implemented a scroll area but within the scroll the I have an expandable text area but the scroll area doesn't take this in to consideration so when the expandable text is clicked it is cutting of the bottom. Is there anyway to fix this? The link that its doing it on is http://www.ashleysark.com/transport

You can see on http://www.ashleysark.com/dogcare the scroll works.

Thanks
Adam

Comment: Sorry try again now, was playing around with the htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page was loaded the height of the content was small and when the vets link was clicked thn the height increased and now the javascript is not aware of it may be one simple fix will be once the accordion call is done try calling  $("#scrollbar1").tinyscrollbar() that should fix the issue.

Comment: I've tried recalling it after the expanded text but no luck, where would you suggest placing it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `$("#scrollbar1").tinyscrollbar()` again after the text has expanded. In fact, you have to call it every time the content of `<div id="scrollbar1">` changes.

Comment: I've tried recalling it after the expanded text but no luck, where would you suggest placing it exactly?